# UINavigationController change child view with another

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have the following structure in Navigation Controller

```
RootViewController
         |
         |--FirstViewController
         |
         |--SecondViewController
```

How can I jump directly from `FirstViewController` to `SecondViewController` without showing  `RootViewController`. I would like to put a button to the `FirstViewController`'s NavigationBar like "Go to SecondViewController."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the appropriate button's action method, initialize the `SecondViewController`, then assemble an NSArray consisting of two elements: the `RootViewController` and the newly initialized `SecondViewController` (in that order, i.e. `Root` at index 0 and `Second` at index 1).

Then call the NavigationController's `setViewControllers:animated:` method, and pass the array of view controllers as the first argument. Remember to `release` the `SecondViewController` after calling this method, or `autorelease` it upon initialization to avoid a memory leak.

Just to clarify, this will cause the `FirstViewController` to be released by the NavigationController.

Sample:

```
- (void) goToSecondViewController
{
    RootViewController *root = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
    SecondViewController *second = [[[SecondViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSArray *controllersArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: root, second, nil];

    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllersArray animated:YES];
}
```

Reference: [UINavigationController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/setViewControllers:animated:)

Comment: Does this hold current as of today? (june 2012) I'm not asking if this works or not but if this is not frowned upon with the current SDK.